# O que está errado no meu código?

Tags: visualg

```
algoritmo "Calculadora"

Var
num1, num2, r: real
operacao: caractere

inicio

EscrevaL("Digite: ")
leia(num1, operacao, num2)

caso operacao "+"
r <- num1 + num2

caso operacao "-"
r <- num1 - num2

caso operacao "*"
r <- num1 * num2

caso operacao "/"
r <- num1 / num2

EscrevaL("Resultado:", r)

fimalgoritmo
```

Basicamente, ele não apresenta os valores corretos, e como eu poderia fazer para digitar a operação direto, tipo assim: 2+2?
Tentei fazer isso ali, tanto que li três variáveis, e não deu certo.
Eu tinha que digitar assim:
2
+
2
Assim, ele iria reconhecer, mas, como a forma que eu relatei acima, não consegui fazer.
Eu inseri o valor 3 + 3, resultou em 9, o que estou errando?
Como posso melhorar o código/corrigir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há uma erro na estrutura do seu código.

Para implementar uma estrutura CASE no VisualG você deve declará-la da seguinte forma:

escolha 
caso 
...
fimescolha

Seu código correto ficaria assim:

```
algoritmo "calculadora"
var
num1, num2, r: real
operacao: caractere

inicio
// Seção de Comandos
EscrevaL("Digite: ")
leia(num1, operacao, num2)

escolha operacao

caso "+"
r <- num1 + num2

caso "-"
r <- num1 - num2

caso "*"
r <- num1 * num2

caso "/"
r <- num1 / num2

fimescolha

EscrevaL("Resultado:", r)

fimalgoritmo
```

Repare nas seções `escolha operacao` e `fimescolha` que encapsulam a estrutura do CASE.

Comment: Obrigado, mas, você consegue responder uma outra dúvida?

Comment: Deu certo. Mas, como eu posso fazer para por exemplo, digitar a expressão direto? Por exemplo: 2+2 ao invés de ter que fazer daquela forma 2, pula linha, +, pula linha, 2? Exemplo: http://prntscr.com/do9npv

Comment: Para digitar tudo em uma linha você precisará ir mais além: terá que implementar um analisador léxico, um parser. Aí o assunto já fica mais para a área de compiladores e linguagens formais. Para expressões simples não é necessário, porém para expressões como (1 + (3 * 5) - 4) / 2, é inviável fazer de outra forma. Não sei se é possível fazer isso em VisualG. Em tempo, se minha resposta anterior responde a sua pergunta, por gentileza, marque-a como tal.